# Keep columns while groupby(periodindex) df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to keep other columns that the df has

```
df=df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='M'))['Close/Last'].mean().reset_index()
```

How can I keep other columns in df?

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Take a minute to read -> [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks

Comment: @GreyMurav is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.agg()` will fit here perfectly:

Just remember to `import numpy as np`

instead of:

```
df=df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='M'))['Close/Last'].mean().reset_index()
```

try this:

```
df=df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='M')).agg({'Close/Last': (np.mean),'Volume':'first','Name':'first'})
```

`.agg()` allows you to choose what to do with the columns (apply functions), but if you just want to keep them, use
.agg({'col1': 'first', 'col2': 'first', ...} etc.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. is there way that this can be done without indexing the `date`?

Comment: You're welcome. I could't understand your question very well.  When you use `groupby()` you are automatically grouping and indexing the df. If you want to get "date" back as a column, use `df.reset_index()`